# Teardrop Looped (Hobbled) Roman Shades

Tags: meaning

What does "teardrop" mean in "[Teardrop Looped (Hobbled) Roman Shades](https://hotblinds.com/product.php?ID=281)"? The word means [a tear-shaped object](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/teardrop), but I didn't see any a tear-shaped object in the first link. Maybe I didn't look hard enough? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have split the description in the wrong place. The shades are 'teardrop looped'. This style of Roman shade (or blind made of cloth) is also called 'hobbled'. They are made so that each section forms a loop, shaped like an elongated conventional teardrop. Because of this, they show pleats (folds) when they are lowered, which is considered a desirable decorative feature.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance and help!